# Why can an interface member not use a private class type?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Consider the following code:

```
ref class ClassA
{

};

interface class IClassA
{
     void DoSomething(ClassA^ a);
};
```

Compiling this code with the Visual C++ 11 Developer Preview yields the following error:

```
error C3981: 'IClassA::DoSomething' cannot be emitted into metadata
```

If `ClassA` is public, the code compiles without error.  Why does the code not compile if `ClassA` is nonpublic?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the C++ compiler in the Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview.

The bug has been fixed and the code compiles without error using the Visual Studio 11 Beta.